# Monitor conversion help needed

Tags: display, autocad, image-conversion

In the early 1990s, I used Autocad 2, which used a CGA/EGA monitor.

I still have the Autocad installed on an old IBM, but I don't have the monitor.

I've seen converters that change the hertz (I think that is the term) to allow CGA/EGA to run on VGA monitors, but they appear to be for installation in video game consoles.

Does anybody know if these converters will work for computer monitors, as well?

Comment: Can you specify your old IBM model?

Comment: It has "PC Server 310" on the front.  It's an old tower model.  It's a pass-along that I got 10 or more years ago.  I think, at one time, it was in a school.  Don't know anything more about it.  Hence my ID "dontknowmuch"

Comment: Would you be able to attach pictures to you question? Back panel picture would be helpful. Also check these links http://www.lenovo.com/psref/pdf/swbook.pdf and https://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=ddse-469mat

Comment: The model number is 8639.  Thanks for the links.   I've made the photos, and I'll try and figure out how to attach them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link.  I was using the comment window, and it doesn't show the buttons.  Have several photos, but had to wrestle with one to get it down to size.  Don't know if it will transmit or not. 
[IBM plugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CLlv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. I was using the comment window, and it doesn't show the buttons. Have several photos, but had to wrestle with one to get it down to size. Don't know if it will transmit or not.

[IBM plugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhjk7.png)